# How to fetch the last row of each mis_dt for each cust_id like the ones highlighted in yellow in the image?

Tags: sql, fetch, record

How to fetch the last row of each mis_dt for each cust_id like the ones highlighted in yellow in the image?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rank() to grade the products by dates and pick the most recent date (desc) or oldest (asc) as order case. Thanks!

```
WITH ranked_products AS (
  SELECT m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM TableName AS m
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_products  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hi,
I need last row of each timestamp of each cust_id,

Comment: Just as the code it, that should give you the latest (by timestamp) record per customer, but if you want the first record, the order date in ASC order

Comment: no i need the last row of each timestamp so desc is the correct way but the results it is fetching is not ordered meaning it is showing all the last dates first and i need it to be grouped by cust_id